# How can I list all possible 3 letter combinations from dict.items()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm making a consecutive letter checker and I got this problem and its supposed to return all the triple letter combinations from the keyboard, however, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong with the last part and how I could make it work? I can only get it to print the 3 letter combinations for the `key()` not the `items()` in the dict. The result I'm looking for is all possible 3 letter combinations from the 'items()' to be printed out in a list.

```
keyboard = {'line1':'qwertyuiop',
            'line2':'asdfghjkl',
                'line3':'zxcvbnm'}

def consequ(key):
    a = []
    for each_key in key:
        for i in range(len(key[each_key])-2):
            a.append(each_key[i:i+3])
    return a
```

I call the function by writing

```
consequ(keyboard)
```

The output is given by this code:

['lin', 'ine', 'ne1', 'e1', '1', '', '', '', 'lin', 'ine', 'ne2', 'e2', '2', '', '', 'lin', 'ine', 'ne3', 'e3', '3']

The wanted output is:

['qwe', 'wer', 'ert', 'rty', 'tyu', 'yui', 'uio', 'iop', 'asd', 'sdf', 'dfg', 'fgh', 'ghj', 'hjk', 'jkl', 'zxc', 'xcv', 'cvb', 'vbn', 'bnm']

Comment: With what do you call `consequ` here?

Comment: consequ(keyboard)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html combination() would be the key here :)

Comment: What output are you *looking for*? Also, how are you *calling this function*? That is a *critical* detail.

Comment: all possible 3 letter combinations for the 3 dict.items()

Comment: **what would that look like**? You realize, there is a way to describe exactly what you want, without ambiguity? Why don't you just provide the actual output?

Comment: yeah sorry i will edit it so that i provide the out put

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store all these combinations of keyboards, you have to iterate over the **values** of the dictionary. You write however:

```
a.append(each_key[i:i+3])
#        ^ key of the dictionary
```

So you have to rewrite it to:

```
def consequ(key):
    a = []
    for line in key.values():
        for i in range(len(line)-2):
            a.append(line[i:i+3])
    return a
```

Or more elegant:

```
def consequ(key):
    a = []
    for line in key.values():
        a += [line[i:i+3] for i in range(len(line)-2)]
    return a
```

These generate:

```
>>> consequ(keyboard)
['zxc', 'xcv', 'cvb', 'vbn', 'bnm', 'asd', 'sdf', 'dfg', 'fgh', 'ghj', 'hjk', 'jkl', 'qwe', 'wer', 'ert', 'rty', 'tyu', 'yui', 'uio', 'iop']
```

Note that most Python interpreters have unordered dictionaries, so the order of the lines can be different.

Comment: Perfect just what i was looking for thanks! I can't accept your answer though it said i can in 6 min